# Can inherited dependencies in rust be aliased in the Cargo.toml file?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a workspace and one of my crates has this :

```ini
[dependencies]
regex = { workspace = true, features = ["unicode"] }
```

but I'd like to perhaps use an alias

```ini
[dependencies]
rgx = { package = "regex", workspace = true, features = ["unicode"] }
```

This is not a possibility so is there an alternative way of aliasing in the toml file itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you want an alias, then it has to be at the workspace level. See the [cargo book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#inheriting-a-dependency-from-a-workspace)

> Along with the workspace key, dependencies can also include these keys:
>
> - `optional`: Note that the `[workspace.dependencies]` table is not allowed to specify optional.
> - `features`: These are additive with the features declared in the `[workspace.dependencies]`
>
> Other than `optional` and `features`, inherited dependencies cannot use **any other dependency key** [..]

This works though:
`Cargo.toml`

```ini
[workpace]
members = ["sub"]

[workspace.dependencies]
rnd = { package = "rand", version = "*" }
rand = { version = "*" }
```

`sub/Cargo.toml`

```ini
#…
[dependencies]
rnd = { workspace = true }
# or if you don't want it renamed in this package
#rand = { workspace = true }
# you cannot use both at the same time though.
```